# Tallying multiple choice entries in a single column in a R dataframe programmatically

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Survey data often contains multiple choice columns with entries separated by commas, for instance:

```
library("tidyverse")
my_survey <- tibble(
  id = 1:5,
  question.1 = 1:5,
  question.2 = c("Bus", "Bus, Walk, Cycle", "Cycle", "Bus, Cycle", "Walk")
)
```

It's desirable to have a function `multiple_choice_tally` that will tally the unique responses for the question:

```
my_survey %>%
  multiple_choice_tally(question = question.2)
### OUTPUT:
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  response count
     <chr> <int>
1      Bus     3
2     Walk     2
3    Cycle     3
```

What is the most efficient and flexible way to construct `multiple_choice_tally`, without any hard coding.

Comment: What about `table`, `strsplit`, and `unlist`? `table(unlist(strsplit(c("Bus", "Bus, Walk, Cycle", "Cycle", "Bus, Cycle", "Walk"), split="[, ]+")))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` from the `tidyr` package to expand the contents in `question.2`. Since you are using `tidyverse`, `tidyr` has been already loaded with `library("tidyverse")` and we don't have to load it again. `my_survey2` is the final output.

```
my_survey2 <- my_survey %>%
  separate_rows(question.2) %>%
  count(question.2) %>%
  rename(response = question.2, count = n)

my_survey2
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  response count
     <chr> <int>
1      Bus     3
2    Cycle     3
3     Walk     2
```

#### Update: Design a Function

We can convert the above code into a function as follows.

```
multiple_choice_tally <- function(survey.data, question){
  question <- enquo(question)
  survey.data2 <- survey.data %>%
    separate_rows(!!question) %>%
    count(!!question) %>%
    setNames(., c("response", "count"))
  return(survey.data2)
}

my_survey %>%
  multiple_choice_tally(question = question.2)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  response count
     <chr> <int>
1      Bus     3
2    Cycle     3
3     Walk     2
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I don't remember seeing separate_rows in the cheatsheets - it's very handy!

Comment: I am glad it helps. I also updated my post to convert the code to a function.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution for this problem is as follows:

```
multiple_choice_tally <- function(survey.data, question) {
  ## Require a sym for the RHS of !!response := if_else
  question_as_quo <- enquo(question)
  question_as_string <- quo_name(question_as_quo)
  target_question <- rlang::sym(question_as_string)

  ## Collate unique responses to the question
  unique_responses <- survey.data %>%
    select(!!target_question) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    .[[1]] %>%
    strsplit(",") %>%
    unlist() %>%
    trimws() %>%
    unique()

  ## Extract responses to question
  question_tally <- survey.data %>%
    select(!!target_question) %>%
    na.omit()

  ## Iteratively create a column for each unique response
  invisible(lapply(unique_responses,
                   function(response) {
                     question_tally <<- question_tally %>%
                       mutate(!!response := if_else(str_detect(!!target_question, response), TRUE, FALSE))

                   }))

  ## Gather into tidy form
  question_tally %>%
    summarise_if(is.logical, funs(sum)) %>%
    gather(response, value = count)

}
```

Which can then be used as follows:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("rlang")
library("stringr")
my_survey <- tibble(
  id = 1:5,
  question.1 = 1:5,
  question.2 = c("Bus", "Bus, Walk, Cycle", "Cycle", "Bus, Cycle", "Walk")
)

my_survey %>%
  multiple_choice_tally(question = question.2)
### OUTPUT:
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  response count
     <chr> <int>
1      Bus     3
2     Walk     2
3    Cycle     3
```